# req.logout() or req.session.destroy() not working with IE 11+ browser

Tags: node.js, session, cookies, passport.js, session-cookies

I have following code in `app.js` when I tried with Chrome, Firefox & Safari `req.logout()` working fine at back-end side but when I tried logout with IE browser than It's not working. I used Following code for setup session and logout API.

```
// set up our express application
app.use(cookieParser());

// required for passport
app.use(session(
    { 
        secret: 'SECRET',
        resave: true,
        saveUninitialized: true,
        maxAge: new Date(Date.now() + 1*60*60*1000),
        store: new MongoStore(
            {
                mongooseConnection : mongoose.connection
            }
        )        
    }
)); // session secret

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session()); // persistent login sessions
```

Logout GET API

```
req.logout();
req.session.destroy(function(err){
   req.user = null;
   req.session = null;
   res.cookies('connect.sid', "", { expires: new Date(0)})
});
```

Please suggest me better way to clear cookies on IE.

Comment: which version of IE you are using?

Comment: IE 11+ I'm using

Comment: Exactly how is it not working? If the session is cleared in the backend the frontend should not be able to access any APIs before logging in again. Also, maybe check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50473675/3349511

Comment: @vesse Actually It resolved, I missed to put `cache: false` in `$.ajax` call. IE stored data in caches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my own way, it's silly mistake.

In IE browser by default, It's caching APIs, My API first time caching after logout and re-login, Because of already caching It's not calling API to the server side, It's taken from the cache.

I found the solution. I used `cache: false` parameter in `$.ajax` call.