# Passport JS does not allow to logout (ExpressJS, PassportJS, React)

Tags: reactjs, express, passport.js

I'm implementing SSO authentication through passport google oidc strategy. Everything works fine for authentication, but I encounter some problems while logging out.

So, here's my Backend logout route

```js
authRouter.post('/logout', async (req, res, next) => {
    req.logout(req.user, (err)=> {
        if (err) return next(err);
    })
    req.session.destroy((err) => {
        res.clearCookie('connect.sid');
    });
})
```

Here's Logout Handler on FrontEnd:

```js
const handlerLogOut = async () => {
        await axios.post('/api/auth/logout', {withCredentials: true})
            .then(res => {
                console.log('response ', res);
            })
    }
```

But while destroying the session, I encounter the next problem which prevent me from logging out:

```
<MyDisk>\<My Folder>\<Project Folder>\server\node_modules\passport\lib\sessionmanager.js:83
    req.session.regenerate(function(err) {
                ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'regenerate')
    at Statement.<anonymous> (<MyDisk>\<My Folder>\<Project Folder>\server\node_modules\passport\lib\sessionmanager.js:83:17)
    at Statement.<anonymous> <MyDisk>\<My Folder>\<Project Folder>\server\node_modules\connect-sqlite3\lib\connect-sqlite3.js:119:32)
```

It seems that session manager trying to regenerate the session which does not exist anymore and here's the error

I've implemented the solution showed in the next question [req.session.destroy and passport logout aren't destroying cookie on client side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50454992/req-session-destroy-and-passport-logout-arent-destroying-cookie-on-client-side) but that doesn't work for me.

Pure `req.logout` doesn't work too.
Session does not destroy and req.user still has user after req.logout has been called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.
Deleted `req.destroy.session()`

```
authRouter.post('/logout', async (req, res, next) => {
req.logout(req.user, (err)=> {
    if (err) return next(err);
})
res.clearCookie('connect.sid');
res.send({isAuth: req.isAuthenticated(), user: req.user})})
```

And on the front-side:

```
await axios.post('/api/auth/logout',{}, {withCredentials: true})
        .then(res => {
            console.log('response ', res);
            setUser(res.data.user)
        })
        .catch(e=> console.log(e))
```

Instead of:

```
await axios.post('/api/auth/logout',{withCredentials: true})
        .then(res => {
            console.log('response ', res);
            setUser(res.data.user)
        })
        .catch(e=> console.log(e))
```